# After rebooting vps "Welcome to nginx!" is now being shown on webpage

Tags: nginx

After rebooting my vps "Welcome to nginx!" is now being shown on my website. For the index page, as well as for other pages. Is there something that could have changed due to the reboot?

Some information from nginx/sites-enabled/default.

```
server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;


        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        # Only for nginx-naxsi : process denied requests
        #location /RequestDenied {
                # For example, return an error code
                #return 418;
        #}

        #error_page 404 /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
```

Comment: isn't that the default page? every thing seems normal, where's your code placed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop a service (Nginx) from being loaded after the system boot, then use one of the below depending on your Linux version:

```
admin@ubuntu:$ sudo chkconfig nginx off  ==> Ubuntu before 12 versions
admin@ubuntu:$ sysv-rc-conf nginx off  ==> (alternative for new ubuntu 12+, but you have to install it: sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf)
```